# Why does the widget break when I pattern match on 1 versus 2 colons?

Tags: r, shiny

As part of a larger app I generate an ANOVA and use the output to later create a dropdown list for creating plots. I have one dropdown for two-way interactions and one for three-way interactions. The interactions are found by the number of colons in the row name. One colon is a two-way interaction, two colons is a three way interaction, and so on.

If I use this code and select for two-way interactions only, or two-way and higher interactions, the dropdown works as expected. The exact same code does not work if I select for a three way interaction.

The MRE below demonstrates this with example data. If you change the pattern match to >0, it shows all the interactions in the dropdown, as expected. If you change it to ==1, it shows only the two-way interactions, as expected. But if you change it to >1 or ==2 the dropdown list breaks, it shows the name of the choices dataframe rather than the choices themselves. If you select that, it is returning the actual selection, but it is not displaying it in the dropdown list.

Am I doing something wrong here?

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(

    uiOutput("ems_int_sel"),
    textOutput("selection")

)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {


    output$ems_int_sel<-renderUI({
      aov_l<-structure(list(Df = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 72), 
                            SS = c(0.199999999999973,0.112500000000021, 2.4500000000001, 25.3124999999997, 4.99999999999986,0.11249999999998, 1.07995057924757e-27, 13.9999999999996), 
                            MS = c(0.199999999999973,0.112500000000021, 2.4500000000001, 25.3124999999997, 4.99999999999986,0.11249999999998, 1.07995057924757e-27, 0.194444444444439),
                            Fvalue = c("1.0286","0.5786", "12.6", "130.1786", "25.7143", "0.5786", "0", ""), 
                            Pvalue = c("0.3139", "0.4494", "7e-04", "<0.0001", "<0.0001","0.4494", "1", ""),
                            Sig = c("", "", "***", "***", "***","", "", ""),
                            EMS = c("Error+40atm", "Error+40rzt", "Error+20atm:rzt","Error+40salt", "Error+20atm:salt", "Error+20rzt:salt", "Error+10atm:rzt:salt","Error")),
                       class = "data.frame",
                       row.names = c("atm", "rzt","atm:rzt", "salt", "atm:salt", "rzt:salt", "atm:rzt:salt", "Residuals"
                                                                                        ))
      req(aov_l)
      
      int_sel<-data.frame(rownames(head(aov_l,-1)))
      int_sel<-filter(.data = int_sel,str_count(string = rownames(head(aov_l,-1)),pattern = ":")>0)#change this 0 to a 1 and the choice does not appear
      names(int_sel)<-"Interactions"
      disp<-TRUE#logical True is a dispersion test
      if(disp){
        int_title<-"Show Three-Way Interaction Plots for Dispersion:"
      } else{
        int_title<-"Show Three-Way Interaction Plots for Means:"
      }
      
      selectInput(inputId = "ems_int_selected",
                  label = int_title,
                  choices = int_sel,
                  multiple = TRUE,
                  width = "100%"
      )
      
    })
    
    output$selection<-renderText({
      input$ems_int_selected
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int_sel<-data.frame(rownames(head(aov_l,-1)))
    int_sel<-deframe(filter(.data = int_sel,str_count(string = rownames(head(aov_l,-1)),pattern = ":")>1)) 
    names(int_sel)<- int_sel # every interaction gets itself as a name / you can change this 
    int_sel <- list("Interactions" = int_sel) # they are in a common list called Interactions
```

Comment: Hunh. @Nir Graham Was it because I was using a dataframe for the options? Thanks!

Comment: data.frames are good for keeping related data together, but in this case it was getting in your way